# Como implementar uma Thread para permitir o cancelamento de preenchimento de StringGrid em Delphi?

Tags: delphi, thread

Eu carrego planilhas em um StringGrid e depois as insiro no banco, queria uma thread para permitir cancelar esta importação, ou seja cancelar o preenchimento do stringGrid, o botão fica "Inclicavel" como vcs ja sabem, até que termine o preenchimento.
   Detalhe, eu mostro esse Rectangle e um progressBar apenas para que o usuario acompanhe. E ele não poderá mecher no sistema enquanto importa, poderá apenas cancelar
Alguem tem idéia de como posso fazer essa thread para o preenchimento do StringGrid?

[image: Quero uma thread para permitir clicar no cancelar para interromper o preenchimento de uma stringGrid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve estar usando alguma estrutura de repetição para o preenchimento certo?

Caso seja `while`, `for`... você pode implementar um `Break`.

```
for i := 0 to Pred(Registros.Count) do
begin
  if (vCancelar = True) then {seria definida como True no click do botão cancelar}
  begin
    Break;
  end;
end;
```

Se estiver percorrendo um `DataSet` então posicione-o no fim dos Registros.

Sobre o Botão ficar "inclicavel" é falha de sua aplicação, como imagino que esteja utiliznado uma estrutura de repetição, qualquer que seja, SEMPRE no inicio ou no fim de qualquer iteração adicione:

```
Application.ProcessMessages;
```

Dessa forma a aplicação pode respirar enquanto o processador executa os métodos em casa iteração.